# Are there transcripts of UDS sessions?

Tags: community, uds

I've been trying to listen to one of the UDS (Ubuntu Developer Summit) sessions today - had a great deal of trouble with interference.

Are there transcripts available of sessions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Audio clips are being saved and uploaded to [this mirror](http://mirrors.tumbleweed.org.za/uds-p/). You should be able to download it after the day is done.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately there aren't any text transcriptions of the sessions, however there are notes taken at each session.

Visit http://summit.ubuntu.com/uds-p/today/ and click on the pad icon (with the green pen) for the notes.

[image: Ubuntu UDS Etherpad Icon]

Hope this helps.

Comment: OK - thanks for that. Doesn't actually help me as such - but then that's more to do with perhaps wanting something that's unavailable :)

Comment: I was at UDS O and the audio kind of sucked. There must be a better way of doing it than the current setup I'm thinking headsets or something.